# How to manage generated files, how long to keep them using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application that generates excel files from a template.

When the new file is streamed to the client I deleted the file. This works fine in my computer, but for whatever reason, when accesing the website from another computer, the file is deleted before streamed to the client, so the file is always empty (0 bytes)
Here is the code:

```
try
{
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ClearHeaders();
  Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + newFN + ".xlsx");                            
  Response.TransmitFile(DestFile);
  Response.Flush();
  Response.End();
}
finally
{
  File.Delete(DestFile);
}
```

Why this works fine from my computer, and it doesn't from another computer?

What can I do to delete generated files and when? I'm thinking in having like a schedule task, to check by date, all files before specific date, and delete them, but is there any other solution?

Comment: Are you sure the file is being generated correctly in the first place on your live server (i.e. that it's not 0 bytes when generated).

Comment: positive sure, it is generated ok, actually if I remove the `File.Delete(DestFile)` I can have it also from different computers with no problem.

Comment: sounds like you need to write code that will check to make sure the file has downloaded properly before deleting it..

Comment: If the file is in use and transmitted, then possible can not be delete it.

Comment: Do you think I can add a delay like: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` before deleting the file?

Comment: Don't do that, change the TransmitFile call to a Response.Write here is an explanation of the difference `TransmitFile - Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream without buffering it in memory.

WriteFile - Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream.`

Comment: also where you have `Response.End()` change that to use `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`

Comment: Is the file being generated dynamically? Can't you use the `Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)` method to send the file from a memory stream?

Comment: @DJKRAZE now in can't open the generated file, not even from my computer, it says: file is corrupted :(

Comment: perhaps the file is corrupt.. can you create an excel file from scratch to test your code.. there are many ways to skin a cat

Comment: I don't understand, the template file has no problem, and the new one is a copy of it, with the new records added :(

Comment: well Somebody while you are scratching your head perhaps you can try some of the recommended suggestions that's all I can say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + newFN + ".xlsx");                            
Response.TransmitFile(DestFile);
Response.Flush();
File.Delete(DestFile);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

But you should consider use the `Response.BinaryWrite` method if the file is being generated dinamically.

Comment: Let me try this from a different computer, which is my issue here.